# errors when trying to insert into the database within a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code, who connect into Database

(CONFIG.PHP)

```
<?php
try{
$ponte_db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=helloius", "asasa", "6233");
}catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s "); 
    $mensagem = "Erro no banco de dados:<br>".$e->getMessage ()."<br>"."Ocorrido em: ".$data;
    mail('suco@suco.com', 'Erro Banco de Dados', $mensagem);
    echo '<script>alert("Desculpe,mas os nossos servidores estao sendo reparados neste exato momento,tente em uma outra hora!");</script>';
}
?>
```

Well in other project (who do a insert) i have this code

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

function DoConfig($param_data){
    $info_config = $ponte_db->prepare("INSERT INTO config (r1) VALUES (:a)");
    $info_config->bindValue(":a", $paran_data);
    $info_config->execute();
  }    
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

if(isset($_POST['data_id']) && $_POST['data_id'] != NULL){

  $data = $_POST['data_id'];
  DoConfig($data);

  
}

}

?>
```

So, when i delete the function DoConfig, and put the pdo insert outside, my database can do a insert, but in this case (insert inside a function) my database don't receive any data, and i get these errors:

> Undefinied variable ponte_db
>
> call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

How can i fix it?

Comment: Sidenote: You have a typo `$paran_data` in `$info_config->bindValue(":a", $paran_data);` which should read as `$param_data` as per `function DoConfig($param_data)`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Great finding.!

Comment: Yes, however I'm next to convinced it's just a typo, hence the "typed in" error message in OP's question `Undefinied variable ponte_db` @ShankarDamodaran which should read as `Undefined` ;-)

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Pretty identical mate. You should write an answer with all the issues you pointed lol ;)

Comment: No, it's ok. I'm afraid it might fall into the `C.O.W.` code category. @ShankarDamodaran

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is no PDO connection in your function because you can't use a variable that is declared outside a function inside a function, so change this:

```
function DoConfig($param_data){
```

to

```
function DoConfig($ponte_db, $param_data){
```

and change the call of the function from this:

```
DoConfig($param_data);
```

to this:

```
DoConfig($ponte_db, $param_data);
```